# Membership.GetAllUsers in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am building a User Management page and am trying to retrieve both the number of registered users and the number currently online using the following code.(FYI...I am using mySQL as the membership provider) There are currently 4 users in the asp_net_users table so at least 4 should come up on the GetAllUsers request.

```
lblOnlineUsers.Text = Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline().ToString()
lblTotalUsers.Text = Membership.GetAllUsers.Count.ToString()
```

The labels are always blank. Even if I put a MsgBox(Membership.GetAllUsers.Count.ToString()) in the pageload, that msgbox never comes up. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you authenticated when you try these method calls?  Are you using automatic log-in?

Comment: Are you sure you have any authenticated users?

Comment: What is the `MsgBox`? Where in your code are you assigning the `label` text?

Comment: If everything is done correctly, labels should display at least zeros. If they are blank, it might turn out their values are overwritten later during the life-cycle. It might help if you could post markup and more of relevant code behind.

Comment: The labels are assigned in the code posted and are the first two lines of the page load event. There are 4 users currently authenticated and stored in the users table.

Comment: The Msgbox code line was put there simply to test whether or not anything was being retrieved from the Membership.GetAllUsers call

Comment: Andrei, there are no further instances of those labels so there value is not being over written, at least not in my code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? It's weird that nothing gets shown. Are you sure you don't overwrite the text later, or that you don't have any UpdatePanels on your page and your page gets only partially refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

You valid your user credential with `ValidateUser` or `UpdateUser` method , and you re-test

Comment: I can already access individual users using Membership.FindUsersByEmail(searchText). I just can't get all users